# display input fields from two objects on one visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object (A). I want my user to be able to update fields witin object A, as well as create a new task using fields on the same screen.

For example, I want the following types of input field on one screen:

objectA_*c.Provider*_c
objectA_*c.ProviderID*_c
task.Subject
task.Category__c

When the user clicks "save", it should update the current record in object A and then add a task associated with object A.

Can this be done? Any advice on how? Also, object A will **always** exist when the user is viewing this screen. And the user viewing this screen will **always** be adding a new task (versus editing an existing one).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You need a controller or extension do this (controller shown here):

```
public with sharing class controller {
    public ObjectA__c objectA { get; set; }
    public Task       task    { get; set; }
    public controller() {
        objectA = ...; // do query from page parameter, etc);
        task = new schema.task();
    }
    public pagereference save() {
        try {
            update objecta;
            task.whatid = objecta.id;
            insert task;
            return new apexpages.standardcontroller(objecta).view();
        } catch(exception e) {
            apexpages.addmessages(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to your ObjectA fields as `{!objecta.provider__c}`, and task fields as `{!task.category__c}`. You can populate other data as well, change the logic around, etc. If you're using the standard controller, you can refer to `{!ObjectA__c.Provider__c}` instead; you'll want to save the standard controller so you can save the data correctly (calling `controller.save()`).